# how to cmap <tab> like the tab in the termimal?

Tags: gvim, gvimrc

when use :e to open files, how to cmap the "Tab" to the function which is similar to the tab function in the terminal? (like when you press tab, it will show all matching files and it will pick the if there is only one file matching)

Answer (score 0):

This was asked in *[How do I make vim do normal (bash like) tab completion for file names?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/526858/how-do-i-make-vim-do-normal-bash-like-tab-completion-for-file-names)*, and the best answer, by @[michael](https://stackoverflow.com/users/59592/michael), uses these settings:

```
set wildmode=longest,list,full
set wildmenu
```